# How to update a table by adding more rows through the click of a button

Tags: php, button, html-table

I'm trying to update a table with the user's request entered in a text box.
So if a user wanted to have 5 rows to enter in data in an order form, they would type in '5' in the text box, hit the update button and it would populate the table with 5 rows.
I believe I have the logic down in my code, but for some reason it isn't updating. Any ideas why?

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th class="textCol">Product Rows:</th>
    <td class="inputCol"><input type="text" name="rows"></td>
    <td><input class="update" type="button" name="update" value="Update"></td>
    <td class="inputCol"></td>
</tr>
</table>

<table class="bottomTable">
    <tr>
        <th class="textCol">Product</th>
        <th class="textCol">Quantity</th>
        <th class="textCol">Unit Price</th>
        <th class="textCol">Total Price</th>
    </tr>
<?
    if (isset($_POST['update']))
    {
        //Execute this code if the update button is clicked.
        $num = $_POST['rows'];

        for ($i=0; $i<$num; $i++) { ?>
          echo "<tr>
                    <td class="inputCol2"><input type="text" name="product[$i]" ></td>
                    <td class="inputCol2"><input type="text" name="quantity[$i]" ></td>
                    <td class="inputCol2">$<input type="text" name="unit[$i]" ></td>
                    <td class="inputCol2">$<input type="text" name="total[$i]" ></td>
                </tr>";
    <? } ?>
<? } else {?>

    <tr>
        <td class="textCol"></td>
        <td class="textCol"></td>
        <td class="textCol">Total Order:</td>
        <td class="inputCol2">$<input type="text" name="total6"></td>
    </tr>
<? } ?>

</table>
```

Comment: where is the code to update??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the input in a form? If it isn't in a form, it submits as a $_GET by default, not a $_POST, so the if() would always find it to be FALSE.

Comment: Thank you, I'd forgotten that it defaults to $_GET method. I added form tags around the table and also changed the input of the update button to 'submit' since it was just 'button' and it works!

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="post">
<table>
    <tr>
        <th class="textCol">Product Rows:</th>
        <td class="inputCol"><input type="text" name="rows"></td>
        <td><input class="update" type="submit" name="update" value="Update"></td>
        <td class="inputCol"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th class="textCol">Product</th>
        <th class="textCol">Quantity</th>
        <th class="textCol">Unit Price</th>
        <th class="textCol">Total Price</th>
    </tr>
<?
    if (isset($_POST['update']))
    {
        //Execute this code if the update button is clicked.
        $num = $_POST['rows'];

        for ($i=0; $i<$num; $i++) { ?>
            <tr>
                <td class="inputCol2"><input type="text" name="'product' . <?=[$i]?>" ></td>
                <td class="inputCol2"><input type="text" name="'quantity' . <?=[$i]?>" ></td>
                <td class="inputCol2">$<input type="text" name="'unit' . <?=[$i]?>" ></td>
                <td class="inputCol2">$<input type="text" name="'total' . <?=[$i]?>" ></td>
            </tr>
    <? } ?>
<? } else {?>
    <tr>
        <td class="textCol"></td>
        <td class="textCol"></td>
        <td class="textCol">Total Order:</td>
        <td class="inputCol2">$<input type="text" name="total6"></td>
    </tr>
<? } ?>
</table>
</form>
```

The php for my values are still not correct, but I'm working on that currently. But it now updates the rows correctly. Thank you for your help!